FeatureServer not displaying all parcels in web app and ArcGIS Online – How to handle large, complex polygon datasets
I'm maintaining an ArcGIS Server application for a client and encountered an issue where not all of the 19,000 complex polygon parcels are displaying in the FeatureServer. The MapServer displays everything correctly, but when using the FeatureServer, only part of the dataset appears, both in the client's web app (built with the CMV framework) and in ArcGIS Online Map Viewer.
The data is stored in SQL Server, and I already resolved an issue where the ObjectID was manually set. After setting the ObjectID column to auto-increment, the MapServer started displaying everything correctly, but the problem persists with the FeatureServer.
My Question:
Could the complexity or volume of the polygon data be causing this issue in the FeatureServer?
If so, what are the best practices for handling large, complex polygon datasets when using a FeatureServer?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Any Question with a numbered list of questions is likely to be quickly closed. Please [Edit] this to specify the exact software versions in use, only briefly mention the cosmetically similar issue, and focus on the problem you want to solved

One question please.
